# OPC-UA client certificate connection problem

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, node-red, opc-ua, raspberry-pi4

Im running node-red OPC-UA Client on my Raspberry pi 4 and OPC-UA server on Omron PLC NJ501-1400. Running without any security policy. But my client cannot connect to server, on debugbar it pops this message.

```
OPC UA connection error: The connection has been rejected by server,
Please check that client certificate is trusted by server.
Err = (connect ENETUNREACH 10.xxx.xxx.x:4840)
```

Any idea how to handle certificates. Or do I have something wrong with server settings?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the concrete components, but ENETUNREACH sounds suspiciously like a networking issue. Can you verify that the client can ping the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add the Certificate of your OPC UA Client in the OPC UA Server's Trusted List of OPC UA Client

> In the NJ-series, it is necessary to register the client certificate in the CPU Unit by
> the Sysmac Studio

Source: [Omron NJ Series Manual](https://assets.omron.eu/downloads/manual/en/v2/w588_nj-series_cpu_unit_opc_ua_users_manual_en.pdf)

Comment: Allready done this or this is what I've done. I took certificate from 
'''
home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-opcua-client/certificates/certificate.pem  
'''
then I converted it to .der, cause PLC accept only .der files and uploaded it into Client authentication/ trusted certificates. And the same ERROOR appeared. But insted of ENETUNREACH is ETIMEDOU.